# android studio getResources().getIdentifier return 0 if apply dexguard

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, dexguard

I have using dexguard in application. I am loading the images  dynamically and displaying in it image view. but image view showing blank. I am using below code.

```
 getResources().getIdentifier(imagename, "drawable", packageName);
```

its returning 0 when I using dexguard 1.7.0.02 for my project(enable the shrinking and disable the obfuscate and optimize for debug build). if I remove the dexguard and run the project it is working fine and showing proper image.

note: the same project with dexguard in eclipse, working fine for above code. I have face this issue in Android Studio only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my self i found solution. The dexguard 7.0 shrinking the resources(for unused ) if you apply the shrinking in android studio.but when  i come to Dexguard 6.0, its is not shrinking the resources(I have observed in eclipse project).so i managed resources like below for Dexguard 7.0 config

```
  -keepresourcefiles res/drawable/**
  -keepresources drawable/**
```